# install guest additions for ubuntu 7.04

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install guest additions for Ubuntu 7.04 (yes, you read that correctly) with a modern Arch Linux host.

Mounting the guest additions iso, I get
[image]

Unfortunately, I seemingly have no virtualbox packages available. Maybe this is related to my apt repositories, which are now pointing to old-releases.ubuntu.com
[image]

Online, I also found sources suggesting to run sudo rcvboxadd setup, to no avail:
[image]

I am glad for any suggestions concerning the installation of guest additions for such an old guest. The host system is Arch Linux, with VirtualBox 5.2.14-1.

Comment: Use older guest additions for older kernel.

Comment: @IporSircer Sounds reasonable - where can I find appropriate guest additions?

Comment: This might not be possible as the addons would need to suport the old OS and the new VM... but you could try hacking something from http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox ... curiosity; 1) why such an old OS, 2) why use addons?

Comment: @user1133275 oh dear :( well, better than nothing, maybe something from there will work! 1) I want to use the exact environment from the book "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation" such that I can follow the examples. 2) The resolution of the VM is totally crappy (1024x768), I am used to 1920x1080!

Comment: Older guest additions worked for me :) I am running the guest additions 4.0.0 which look good enough to me. So if you provide your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be possible as the addons would need to support the old OS and the new VM... but you could try hacking something from

http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox